# Managing Code Variants in C: changing variable that repeats all over the code

Tags: c, git, scalability

I've been working on a project with very large datasets (in the order of terabytes). I am at the point now where I want to test different versions of my code.

In particular (in the simplest case), I want to change the type of some variables that are repeated all over the code (I pass them to functions) and I want to change their type from double to float (in order to save space in memory).

**My question is:**

> What is the best way (I'm currently using git) to manage this two variation of the code?

I don't want to use simple branching because my idea is not to merge at the end of the tests, I'll want to keep both (or even multiple) versions of my program. what is the best way to do that? I'd like to avoid code repetition and do it in the most scalable way

I've thought about using #defines, but this could be a good idea for very few variations, I'd like to have as much scalability as possible

I'm programming in C.

**Edit**: `typedef` can be useful in this case. But what if I want to use different functions according to my variables type? I know in C++ you could use templates, but in C? What would be the best way?

Comment: This seems like exactly the kind of thing that a `typedef` would be used for.

Comment: I think this may be a case for a branch (if the variations are big). The branches don't have to merged, it is your workflow. The advantage of the branch is that there will be a history back to the common original code. Else a fork could work.

Comment: There is no language named "C/C++", you either program in C *or* you program in C++. The two languages, though somewhat similar on the surface, are actually completely different.

Comment: @MattMcNabb not in C. :)

Comment: @Mario question was originally tagged C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `typedef`.  Put it in some common, low-level header file in your project, like this:

```
typedef double real_t;
```

Then you can carefully, just once, replace `double` with `real_t` everywhere that it makes sense (you can't necessarily replace it *everywhere*, because some places it may not make sense, e.g. where you call external functions, or use `double` for something unrelated).

Then, to switch between two versions, just replace `double` with `float` in one place.  Or:

```
typedef MY_REAL_TYPE real_t;
```

Then you can control it from  your build system by setting `-DMYREAL_TYPE=double` in your Makefile etc.